# Query about UICollectionView

Tags: ios, xcode, indexing, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

First of all, sorry for the silly question, but i am new to collectionview and little confuse too.

I am working on `UICollectionView`. I am passing image to it from my `plist` file. I have 6 to 8 items of array, and every array has 6 items(NSString).
I am using this code..

```
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSArray *temp = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

UIImage *cellImage;
cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[temp objectAtIndex:2]];
cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
```

Now, I want to change index to `objectAtIndex:5` when i get flag 1 or 0, and it should be for perticular item.

```
UIImage *cellImage;

if (myInt == 1) {

    cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[temp objectAtIndex:2]];
}
else{
    cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[temp objectAtIndex:5]];
}

cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
```

If I am doing this then either i get `index 2` or `index 5` for every item. Is it possible to get `index 2` for some item and `index 5` for some item based on flag ?? or Is there any other way to do so ?

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit :
My collectionview has 3 images(items) in a row. If I tap any icon, it will redirect to the new view to read some documents. There is a done button in that view on bar, which gives a flag value (0/1). Now if I get flag 1 then I want to change collectionview icon for that case only. But here, By this given code all icon replaced by `index 5`, but I want only first icon from `index 5` and other 2 icon from `index 2`. like Just to differentiate that first doc is reviewed.

sorry if it confuse.

Comment: Now what is ur problem? The above code is not working?? Didn't get ur question??

Comment: Its working, but not for particular item. let me edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to use myInt that way in this situation. Instead you want to create an array in your collection view controller to keep track of any items that were selected. So, if you had a property called reviewedDocs (pointing to an NSMutableArray), you would add the indexPath of the cell you selected.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.reviewedDocs addObject:indexPath];
}
```

Then, in your cellForItemAtIndexPath: method, you would select the image based on whether the current indexPath matches one in the reviewedDocs array.

```
UIImage *cellImage;

if ([self.reviewedDocs containsObject:indexPath]) {

    cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[temp objectAtIndex:5]];
}
else{
    cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[temp objectAtIndex:2]];
}
```

The image won't change until you come back to the collection view controller, and you reloadData. I wasn't sure what you're using the myInt flag for, but if, for example, you had a done button and a cancel button, you might return 1 or 0 respectively for those two actions. In the viewDidAppear method of you collection view controller, you could then remove the last object from reviewedDocs, if myInt is 0, indicating that the user just cancelled out rather than reviewing the doc (and then call reloadData on the collection view).